# интроспекция и автодополнение для собственных модулей в PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, pycharm

Работаю под `OS Linux`, `IDE PYCharm`, `Python3.5`.

Проблема заключается в следующем: при написании собственных модулей невозможно подключить их в другом скрипте так что бы происходила интроспекция кода и автодополнение.

Иными словами: я подключаю встроенный модуль, он отображается в строке автодополения, я могу работать с его методами и переменными через автодополение; если я пытаюсь подклчить модуль собсвенного написания лежащий в одной папке с редактируемым скриптом, IDE его не видит в автодополнении, подчёркивает красным, к содержимому модуля обратиться невозможно.

Тем не менее при запуске скрипт отрабатывает без ошибок.

Каким образом возможно заставить `IDE PYCharm` видеть самописные модули?

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решается следующим образом:

В диспетчере проектов необходимо найти папку со своими модулями; кликнуть по ней правой кнопкой мыши и в контекстном меню выбрать: Mark Directory as -> Sources Root

IDE сразу же увидит написанные модули, интроспекция и автодополнеие начинают функциониовать нормально.